# How to make this dynamic link open new tab?

Tags: html, hyperlink

```
 <a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="https://mydomain.com/register/<?php echo $locat?>">CONTINUE BROWSING &raquo;</a>
```

Hey guys i have 3 different registration user types that all go to my "payment page" where i display 3 different packages..

i have one of those contiinue browsing links but if a user clicks that they cant go back because the unique token expires....

i want this link to open a new tab or page when they click it this way i dont have to worry if a user was just click the link to see what it was but then cant go back to actually sign up.... ive read online but it keeps causing errors on page when i try to do it./

Any tips, i appreciate sorry for the easy question but i do appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://yourwebsite.com/">link name</a>
```

or you could use `<a rel="ext" href="external website>link name</a>` and have a script add `target="_blank"` to all anchors with `rel="ext"` once the document is loaded.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).find('a[rel="ext"]').attr("target", "_blank");
  });
</script>
...
<body>
   <a rel="ext" href="some website">some name</a>
```

Comment: the links change depending on user type isnt that what for echo $locat is for? sorry im not a dev. is there any way you can take my code and input what you mean?

Comment: Hey i just did this and it worked....href="https:// domain .com/ register/<? php echo $ locat?>" <a target="_blank"> CONTINUE BROWSING & raquo;</a>  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`<a target="blank" href="yourlink">link name</a>`
Because `blank` instead of `_blank` will force the browser to open the same tab if the link is clicked again which is pretty nice for me. So try it out